# Java 6 Threads - different behaviour with "implements Runnable" and "extends Thread"

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, java-6

can someone explain me why output after execution this program is so different?

First of all, classes:
Thread extending java.lang.Thread

```
public class UsingThreadExtension extends Thread {

    public UsingThreadExtension(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation of java.lang.Runnable:

```
public class UsingRunnableImplementation implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }
}
```

And main class:

```
public class ThreadsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UsingThreadExtension threadA = new UsingThreadExtension("Thread A");
        UsingRunnableImplementation runnableImplementation = new UsingRunnableImplementation();
        Thread threadB = new Thread(runnableImplementation, "Thread B");

        //threadA.start();
        threadB.start();

        try {
            //threadA.join();
            threadB.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //threadA.run();
        threadB.run();

        System.out.println("Main thread says hello!");
    }
}
```

In this combination output is like this:

```
0 Thread B

1 Thread B

2 Thread B

3 Thread B

4 Thread B

Main thread says hello!
```

And after commenting threadB part and uncommenting threadA, there is something like this:

```
0 Thread A

1 Thread A

2 Thread A

3 Thread A

4 Thread A

0 main

1 main

2 main

3 main

4 main

Main thread says hello!
```

Can someone tell me, what exactly causes such difference? Any hints appreciated. I suppose that, it is connected with overriding java.lang.Thread.run() method in threadA, but why threadB, does not run runnable in second case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Second Case (`threadA.run()`) : -**

Since `threadA` is a reference of type `UsingThreadExtension`: -

```
UsingThreadExtension threadA = new UsingThreadExtension("Thread A");
```

So calling the `run` method on threadA like this: -

```
threadA.run();
```

will execute the *run* method of `UsingThreadExtension` in the *main* thread only. And thus, the name of the *thread* is *main* in `0 main, 1 main, etc.` in the 2nd output.

---

**First Case (`threadB.run()`) : -**

Since `threadB` is a *reference* of type `Thread` pointing to an *instance* of `Thread` only.

```
Thread threadB = new Thread(runnableImplementation, "Thread B");
```

So, invoking the *run* method on it like: -

```
threadB.run();
```

will execute the *run()* method overriden in the *Thread class* again in the `main` thread only. But since *run()* method of *Thread class* doesn't actually print anything. And hence you didn't get any output for `threadB.run()`.

Answer (score 3):

`Runnable.run()` doesn't start a new thread, it just runs the method -- just like any other method. If you want to spin off a new thread, you always have to use `Thread.start()` (or submit the `Runnable` to an executor).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP is intentionally invoking `run` on both the threads. He just wants to know, why the `run` method is executed only in case of `threadB` and not in `threadA`. See the output.

Answer (score 0):

When you construct a `Thread` passing it a `Runnable` instance, it stores that instance away in a private field. The default `run()` method of `java.lang.Thread` is essentially

```
if(target != null) target.run();
```

So presumably what happens in your thread B case is that you `start()` the thread, and when it completes it internally does `target = null`. Then when you call the thread's `run()` method later it no longer has a reference to the target `Runnable` so does not run it.

If you did it the other way round, first calling `run()` on the main thread and later calling `start()` you'd see both lots of logging.

In the `extends Thread` case the `run()` method is overridden directly, so this null check is bypassed.